# export html table to xlsx with style

Tags: css, angular, excel, converters, xlsx

How can I convert an HTML table with the ID "mytable" in Angular to an Excel file with the xlsx extension, while preserving the styles (such as borders and colors) defined in the HTML file (which are inline styles), and apply them to the Excel file?

Comment: Please outline the research you have done and what code you have tried as a result.